# How to change the image orientation in swift

Tags: swift, imageview

i have an image view, the image view will get image from camera but the problem is when i want to display the image view the orientation of the image is landscape.
here is my code

```
class ResultViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
var userData2 = userData()

    var base64String1: String!
    var decodedData1: Data!
    var decodedImage1: UIImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageResult: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        base64String1 = userData2.fotoIDString!
        decodedData1 = Data(base64Encoded: base64String1, options: [])!
        decodedImage1 = UIImage(data: decodedData1)!
        imageResult.image = decodedImage1



       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transfor orientation of your imageView

```
imageResult.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

Comment: `Swift 4.2` `imageResult.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)`

Answer (score 1):

This following code rotate an image 90 degrees in **Swift 3**

```
imageResult.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
```